# How to add specific characters of an elements of a list to a tuple

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a list containing some elements that looks like this:

```
data = ["1: 6987", "2: 5436", "7: 9086"]
```

Is it possible to tuple the elements where it would look like this:

```
tuple_data = [("1", 6987) , ("2", 5436), ("7", 9086)]
```

Comment: do you really want the first element of tuples as string?

Answer (score 2):

```
splits = [record.split(": ") for record in data]
tuple_data = [(first, int(second)) for first, second in splits]
```

Can also do it in one line if you like:

```
tuple_data = [(first, int(second)) for first, second in [record.split(": ") for record in data]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` and `split` can be used for this:

```
 data = ["1: 6987", "2: 5436", "7: 9086"]
 map(lambda i: (i.split(': ')[0], int(i.split(': ')[1])), data)
```

Result:

```
 [('1', 6987), ('2', 5436), ('7', 9086)]
```

`lambda` defines an anonymous function which `split`s each element on `': '` and adds the first and second part of that split to a tuple, while `map` applies the anonymous (lambda) function to each element in `data`.

There may be a more elegant way :).

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension is one way:

```
data = ["1: 6987", "2: 5436", "7: 9086"]

res = [(i.split(':')[0], int(i.split(':')[1])) for i in data]

# [('1', 6987), ('2', 5436), ('7', 9086)]
```

Syntax is simpler if you want only integers:

```
res = [tuple(map(int, i.split(':'))) for i in data]

# [(1, 6987), (2, 5436), (7, 9086)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
data = [(i[:i.find(':')], int(i[i.find(':')+1:].strip())) for i in data]
```

result:

[('1', 6987), ('2', 5436), ('7', 9086)]